# Angular Factor Call not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call the update / put method in the factory which will in turn save the changes on the form to the database via an API call.  But I get a console error below.  The update function is getting called from the button click fine, but it doesn't call the factory and API from there. What am I missing? Thank you!

I updated my code with the suggestion below but now have this error:

My console error: "Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-%20memberUpdate

---

var securityApp = angular.module('securityApp', ['ngRoute']).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {

```
$routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'PartialPages/members.html',
        controller: 'membersController'
    })

    .when('/memberDetail/:memberID', {
        templateUrl: 'PartialPages/memberDetail.html',
        controller: 'memberDetailController'
    })

    .when('/memberEdit', {
        templateUrl: 'PartialPages/memberEdit.html',
        controller: 'memberEditController'
    });

});


securityApp.factory('memberUpdate', function ($resource) {       
    return $resource('/api/Members/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
});


securityApp.controller('memberDetailController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, memberUpdate) {

    var id = $routeParams.memberID;

    $http.get('/api/Members/' + $routeParams.memberID).success(function (data) {
        $scope.member = data;
    })
    .error(function () {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
    })

    $scope.update = function () {
        memberUpdate.update({ id: id }, $scope.member);
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$resource is in a different module  so you need to include it.
var securityApp = angular.module('securityApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).
```

her how you install it https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource

Comment: Thank you.  I added the angular resource script and that solved the problem.

Comment: the correct syntax is: var securityApp = angular.module('securityApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).

Comment: @Austin Harris yes sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 3):

You need to inject memberUpdate into the controller dependencies.

```
securityApp.controller('memberDetailController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, memberUpdate) {

    var id = $routeParams.memberID;

    $http.get('/api/Members/' + $routeParams.memberID).success(function (data) {
        $scope.member = data;
    })
    .error(function () {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
    })

    $scope.update = function () { // you don't need to pass $scope and memberUpdate since they are already available into the scope
        memberUpdate.update({ id: id }, $scope.member);
    };

});
```

Comment: I get this error when I try your suggestions: "Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-%20memberUpdate